# Concatenate a list of pandas dataframes together

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have a list of Pandas dataframes that I would like to combine into one Pandas dataframe.  I am using Python 2.7.10 and Pandas 0.16.2

I created the list of dataframes from:

```
import pandas as pd
dfs = []
sqlall = "select * from mytable"

for chunk in pd.read_sql_query(sqlall , cnxn, chunksize=10000):
    dfs.append(chunk)
```

This returns a list of dataframes

```
type(dfs[0])
Out[6]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

type(dfs)
Out[7]: list

len(dfs)
Out[8]: 408
```

Here is some sample data

```
# sample dataframes
d1 = pd.DataFrame({'one' : [1., 2., 3., 4.], 'two' : [4., 3., 2., 1.]})
d2 = pd.DataFrame({'one' : [5., 6., 7., 8.], 'two' : [9., 10., 11., 12.]})
d3 = pd.DataFrame({'one' : [15., 16., 17., 18.], 'two' : [19., 10., 11., 12.]})

# list of dataframes
mydfs = [d1, d2, d3]
```

I would like to combine `d1`, `d2`, and `d3` into one pandas dataframe.  Alternatively, a method of reading a large-ish table directly into a dataframe when using the `chunksize` option would be very helpful.

Answer (score 511, accepted):

Given that all the dataframes have the same columns, you can simply [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) them:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.concat(list_of_dataframes)
```

Comment: Note that column names must match for the data frames to be concatenated vertically. Otherwise, the default behavior is that they will be concatenated horizontally.

Answer (score 24):

**Just to add few more details:**

*Example:*

```
list1 = [df1, df2, df3]

import pandas as pd
```

- Row-wise concatenation & ignoring indexes

  ```
  pd.concat(list1, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
  ```

  **Note:** If column names are not same then *NaN* would be inserted at different column values
- Column-wise concatenation & want to keep column names

  ```
  pd.concat(list1, axis=1, ignore_index=False)
  ```

  If **ignore_index=True**, column names would be filled with numbers starting from 0 to (n-1), where *n is the count of unique column names*

Answer (score 12):

If the dataframes DO NOT all have the same columns try the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(map(dict,df_list))
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me on Python 3.6.5 / Pandas v0.23.0. It errors with `TypeError: data argument can't be an iterator`. Converting to `list` first (to mimic Python 2.7) comes up with unexpected results too.

Comment: and if the all dataframes have the same column, how should we do ?

Answer (score 8):

You also can do it with functional programming:

```
from functools import reduce
reduce(lambda df1, df2: df1.merge(df2, "outer"), mydfs)
```

Comment: `from functools import reduce` to use `reduce`

Comment: Would not recommend doing a pairwise merge for multiple DataFrames, it is not efficient at all. See `pd.concat` or `join`, both accept a list of frames and join on the index by default.

Answer (score 0):

`concat` also works nicely with a list comprehension pulled using the "loc" command against an existing dataframe

```
df = pd.read_csv('./data.csv') # ie; Dataframe pulled from csv file with a "userID" column

review_ids = ['1','2','3'] # ie; ID values to grab from DataFrame

# Gets rows in df where IDs match in the userID column and combines them 

dfa = pd.concat([df.loc[df['userID'] == x] for x in review_ids])
```

Answer (score -1):

pandas `concat` works also as well in addition with `functools`

```
from functors import reduce as reduce
import pandas as pd
deaf = pd.read_csv("http://www.aol.com/users/data.csv")
for q in range(0, Len(deaf)):
  new = map(lambda x: reduce(pd.concat(x))
```

Comment: please to be specifying in more detail your rationale. thank you.