# Combine a list of pandas dataframes that do not have the same columns to one pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, merge

I have three Dataframes : `df1, df2, df3` with the same number of "rows" but different number of "columns" and different "column" labels. I want to "merge" them in one single dataframe with the order `df1,df2,df3` and keeping the original column labels.

I've read in [Combine a list of pandas dataframes to one pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32444138/combine-a-list-of-pandas-dataframes-to-one-pandas-dataframe) that this can be done by:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(map(dict,df_list))
```

But I cannot fully understand the code. I assume `df_list` is:

```
df_list = [df1,df2,df3]
```

But what is `dict`? A dictionary of `df_list`? How to get it?

Comment: I think in this case `dict` refers to the dict method in the python built-ins. It's mapped to df_list.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me on Python 3.6.5 / Pandas v0.23.0. It errors with `TypeError: data argument can't be an iterator`. Converting to `list` first (to mimic Python 2.7) comes up with unexpected results too. I think the version differences are insurmountable here, look for a more recent question.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by:

```
        df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, sort=False)
        df = pd.concat([df, df3], axis=1, sort=False)
```

Comment: or just `pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1, sort=False)`

Comment: Yes, much simpler :)