# How to fix Python Pandas plots?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, anaconda

I'm having a peculiar problem with making graphs from several comma-separated lists in Pandas. Basically, I want to make four graphs at once. If I run the code blocks 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, and 2.4 separately, I get the correct plots.

[image of correct plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2l4e.png)

However, if I run all of the code at once, I get this strange-looking plot that isn't correct at all:

[image of incorrect plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BZbT.png)

Is there any way to fix this?

Here's the Kaggle data repo that has the input files. Download, unzip, and rename appropriately if you wish to replicate the issue: [Kaggle repo](https://www.kaggle.com/maksymshkliarevskyi/reddit-data-science-posts)

And here's the code. I'm using Spyder 4.1.5 with Python 3.8.5 (Anaconda version). Apologies in advance for the length of the code:

```
"""

This program will use pandas to take multiple comma-seperated list files from 
https://www.kaggle.com/maksymshkliarevskyi/reddit-data-science-posts and randomly output data from them.

Filename: Poeth_Lab_11-1.py

Author: Dean Poeth

Created on 4/13/2021

"""

#%% Initialization sequence

#imports
import os
import pandas as pd


# read data. Idea for reading Windows file from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37400974/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-in-position-2-3-trunca

input_folder = "reddit_aiml/"

# list of files

file_list = os.listdir(input_folder)

# empty list to store dataframes

df_list = []

# read in dataframes
for file in file_list:
    print("loading", file)
    
    temp_df = pd.read_csv(input_folder + file)
    
    #add dataframe to list
    df_list.append(temp_df)
    
#join together    
# join them together
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32444138/concatenate-a-list-of-pandas-dataframes-together

aiml_data = pd.concat(df_list)

# get a random sample of data to see if things work without
# taking forever!

"###########------------REMOVE WHEN HOMEWORK IS COMPLETE!------------###########"
#aiml_data = aiml_data.sample(1000) 

"""^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^"""

"""Row check goes here"""
 
aiml_data['date_posted'] = pd.to_datetime(aiml_data['created_timestamp'])

aiml_data['date_posted'].head()

# explore data

aiml_data.info()

summary = aiml_data.describe(include='all')

# date formatting

aiml_data['author_created_date'] = pd.to_datetime(aiml_data['author_created_utc'], unit='s')
aiml_data['author_created_date'].head()                                                  
                                 

aiml_data['created_date'] = pd.to_datetime(aiml_data['created_date'])   

#%% Q 2.1 plot total number of posts across all subreddits over time

"###########------------COMPLETE------------###########"

print("------------Question 2.1------------")

print()

#aiml_data['created_date'].dt.date


total_post_plot = aiml_data.groupby(aiml_data['created_date'].dt.year)['created_date'].count().plot(kind='line')

total_post_plot.set(xlabel="Year", ylabel="Post Count",
             title = "AI/ML Total number of posts over time (all subreddits)")

total_post_plot.get_figure().savefig('totalPostPlot.png')

print("Plot drawn. See Plots area for more details.")
print()
print()

#%% Q 2.2 distribution of post scores

"###########------------COMPLETE------------###########"

print("------------Question 2.2------------")

print()
#post_score_dist = aiml_data.groupby(aiml_data['created_date'].dt.year)['score'].count().plot(kind='bar', sharex=False)

#post_score_dist.set(xlabel="Year", ylabel="Score",
            # title = "AI/ML Post score distribution (all subreddits)")

#post_score_dist.get_figure().savefig('postScoreDist.png')



post_score_dist = aiml_data['score'].plot.hist()

post_score_dist.set(xlabel="Score", ylabel="Post Count", title = "AI/ML Post Score Distribution")

post_score_dist.get_figure().savefig('postScoreDistribution.png')

print("Plot drawn. See Plots area for more details.")
print()
print()


#%% Q 2.3 posts by day of week

"###########------------COMPLETE------------###########"

print("------------Question 2.3------------")

print()

# Which day of the week was something posted?

aiml_data['dow'] = aiml_data['created_date'].dt.day_name()


aiml_data['dow'] = pd.Categorical(aiml_data['dow'], categories=
    ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'],
    ordered=True)

#Print the plot directly (Minimal Formatting)
#aiml_data.groupby('dow')['created_date'].count().plot(kind='bar')

dow_plot = aiml_data.groupby('dow')['created_date'].count().plot(kind='bar')

dow_plot.set(xlabel="Day of the Week", ylabel="Total Number of Posts",
             title = "AI/ML Posts per Day of the week")

#Save figure to file

dow_plot.get_figure().savefig('postsByDOW.png')

print("Plot drawn. See Plots area for more details.")
print()
print()


#%% Q 2.4 Plot the total number of posts per hour of the day.

"###########------------COMPLETE------------###########"

print("------------Question 2.4------------")

print()

aiml_data['hod'] = aiml_data['created_date'].dt.hour



#aiml_data['hod'] = pd.Categorical(aiml_data['hod'], categories=
#    ['1pm', '2pm'],
#    ordered=True)

#Print the plot directly (Minimal Formatting)
#aiml_data.groupby('hod')['created_date'].count().plot(kind='bar')

hod_plot = aiml_data.groupby('hod')['created_date'].count().plot(kind='bar')

hod_plot.set(xlabel="Hour of the day", ylabel="Total Number of Posts",
             title = "AI/ML Posts per hour of the day")

#Save figure to file

hod_plot.get_figure().savefig('postsByHOD.png')

print("Plot drawn. See Plots area for more details.")
print()
print()
```

Comment: Have you tried importing matplotlib.pyplot as plt and adding "plt.figure()" before calling each of the plots?

Comment: Not yet. I'll try it later today.

Comment: Hey, could you please give me an example for the syntax of adding plt.figure() before calling the plots?

Comment: Well, first you'd need to import matplotlib (import matplotlib.pyplot as plt) and then add plt.figure() above each line you call the plot function (e.g. line above total_post_plot = ...).