# How to convert a dictionary with DataFrame values to DataFrame using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I want to join data frames using *pandas*.

I have several data frames. For example, two of them are:

df1=

```
           A      B      C
0    1    1.1    1.2    1.3
1    2    1.4    1.5    1.4
```

and df2=

```
           A      B      C
0    1    2.1    2.2    2.3
1    2    2.4    2.5    2.4
```

I would like to join them into 1 data frame like:

```
                  A      B      C
R1     0    1    1.1    1.2    1.3
       1    2    1.4    1.5    1.4
                  A      B      C
R2     0    1    2.1    2.2    2.3
       1    2    2.4    2.5    2.4
```

I tried to put them into a dictionary and convert them to the DataFrame like:

```
dict_val = {}
dict_val['R1'] = df1
dict_val['R2'] = df2
df_join = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_val)
```

however, I am getting the following error:
**ValueError: Must pass 2-d input.**

How can I make this type of data frame?

Comment: Try `df_join = pd.concat(dict)` (NB. Don't use `dict` as variable name, this is a python built-in)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenate a list of pandas dataframes together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32444138/concatenate-a-list-of-pandas-dataframes-together)

Comment: I am not using dict as a variable I forgot to change it here (I will modify it now). The variables aren't causing an issue

Comment: fyi -- you should read the docs of `pandas.DataFrame.from_dict()`. It doesn't expect a dictionary of already created data frames. In the "Getting Started" section of documentation, there's a header labeled "How do I combine data from multiple tables?". You should read that too.

Comment: @MichaelCao, I need to add an additional column to each data frame and then specify the indices. I wondered if there is any way to convert a dictionary with pandas.DataFrame as its values to another pandas.DataFrame?

Comment: @PaulH, thanks for the information. But they do not sure this example. I need to specify 'R1' and 'R2' (and so on) for each data frame I am joining

Comment: This example *is* demonstrated. Read more closely the examples about air quality that use the `key` argument

Comment: Have you tested `concat` as I suggested?

Answer (score 0):

> *Try `df_join = pd.concat(dict)` (NB. Don't use `dict` as variable name, this is a python built-in)*
>
> <sup>- [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75747803/how-to-convert-a-dictionary-with-dataframe-values-to-dataframe-using-pandas#comment133623944_75747803) by [mozway](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16343464/mozway)</sup>

[`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) is the simplest [and probably the most efficient] way to join multiple DataFrames together.

> *I need to add an additional column to each data frame and then specify the indices* - [about `R1` and `R2`]

You can use the `keys` argument to do so

```py
df_join = pd.concat([df1,df2], keys=['R1','R2'])

# for a list of DataFrames of unknown length: 
# df_join = pd.concat(dfs_list, keys=[f'R{i}' for i in range(1, len(dfs_list)+1)])
```

---

And if you really want to combine them as dictionaries first for some reason, you can do it on loop

```py
dfs_list = [df1, df2]
index_join, data_join = [], []
for di, df in enumerate(dfs_list):
    data_join += df.to_dict('records')

    index_join += [(f'R{di}', *i) for i in df.index] # if df is multi-indexed
    # index_join += list(df.index) # if df is not multi-indexed

df_join = pd.DataFrame(data=data_join, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(index_join))
```

or with dictionary comprehension

```py
df_join = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    (f'R{di}', *df_index): df_row for di,df in enumerate([df1,df2]) 
    for df_index, df_row in df.to_dict('index').items()
}, orient="index")
```

which effectively does the same as if you edited your code to

```py
dict_val = {}
dict_val.update({('R1',i1,i2):row for (i1,i2), row in df1.to_dict('index').items()})
dict_val.update({('R2',i1,i2):row for (i1,i2), row in df2.to_dict('index').items()})
df_join = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_val, orient="index")
```