# How to label outputs of looping

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops

EDITED to focus on outputs rather than the concat:

I am scraping data through an API which requires different codes to scrape various datasets (for example, country codes) - I obviously don't want to copy and paste the same few lines of code to pull the data and manipulate it so was hoping to loop through a list of country codes and do it this way.

```
thislist = ["ES", "EE", "LT"]

for x in thislist:
    headers = api.box(id=x, meta=True)
    countrydf = api.box(id=x)
    countrydf .index = countrydf['Date']
    countrydf .index = pd.to_datetime(countrydf .index)
    countrydf = countrydf.iloc[: , 2:]  
print(countrydf)
```

The issue is that this gives me only the last dataframe (LT) - how do I need to change this so that I can find all dataframes (ES, EE, LT etc) so that I can then concat them together.

Any help much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Construct a list of dataframes and then use [pandas.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenate a list of pandas dataframes together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32444138/concatenate-a-list-of-pandas-dataframes-together)

Comment: It helps with the merging but the output of the above is still just the dataframe with country code 'LT' - so I don't know how to find the ES or EE dataframes if that makes sense

Comment: `headers = api.box(id=x, meta=True)`: you define *headers* but do not use it. Is that something to place in a list as well?

Comment: Regarding "EDITED to focus on outputs rather than the concat:": my answer gets the output in a list. It is not about concatenating, although it lets you do that later if needed. Is this satisfactory to you?

Comment: That being said, you're not providing a [MRE], so we can only guess.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are overwriting countrydf with each iteration. Maybe append to somewhere or change the index before going to the next item in your list

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to create a local list consisting of all the fields of one entry within the loop and append them at the end of loop to the dataframe as given in example 1 [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-one-row-in-an-existing-pandas-dataframe/).

```py
# dummy df for example
dict = {'Name':['Martha', 'Tim', 'Rob', 'Georgia'],
        'Maths':[87, 91, 97, 95],
        'Science':[83, 99, 84, 76]
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(dict)

df.loc[len(df.index)] = ['Amy', 89, 93]
```

Inside this local list obtain the data from the API and finally add it to the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Start by making a function of your scraping:

```py
def api_to_df(x):
    '''Convert one api call into a datafame''' 
    headers = api.box(id=x, meta=True)
    temp_df = api.box(id=x)
    temp_df.index = countrydf['Date']
    temp_df.index = pd.to_datetime(countrydf .index)
    return temp_df.iloc[: , 2:]
```

Then here is your list, via [comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html):

```
thislist = ["ES", "EE", "LT"]
df_list  = [api_to_df(x) for x in thislist]
```

You're not doing anything with *headers*, by the way, you define it but do not use it. What is it for?